# Constructing a type assignable to generic type T but not to generic type U

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to construct a type that is assignable to a generic type `T` but is not assignable to a generic type a `U`? Consider the following:

```
// Assume that these are generic types that extend the following.
interface T {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}

interface U {
    foo: "baz";
}
```

I specifically want a type, say `X`, that can take in an object of type `T` but specifically exclude anything that matches `U`. I tried using `Exclude<T, U>`, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
type X = Exclude<T, U>;

const xObj1: X = {
    foo: "test", // This should be valid
    bar: 4
};
const xObj2: X = {
    foo: "baz", // This should error, but it doesn't.
    bar: 2
};
```

Comment: This is not possible without a generic helper function to do the inferencing. TypeScript does not have a concept of "NOT" types.

Comment: Still, you could use this: https://tsplay.dev/w843dw

Comment: If by "generic" you mean "arbitrary" then no, you can't, since TypeScript lacks *negated types* and therefore there is no way to write `T & not U` for arbitrary `T` and `U`.  But you can always write a generic *constraint* that acts this way, with a helper function, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NlDYGN) shows. But that only works for "arbitrary" `T` and `U` if you curate how inference happens there (by default `{foo: "baz"}` will be inferred as `{foo: string}` and then it will fail to be seen as `U`).

Comment: ... Do you want to see either my or @vr.'s version written up as an answer?  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: @jcalz Your answer actually was the solution is was looking for! If you could turn that into an answer, I can mark it as the solution. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript lacks *negated types* (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) but never merged into the language) of the form `not U`, so there's no *specific* type `T & not U` for arbitrary `T` and `U`.

If `T` and `U` happen to be [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and you want to filter out all members of `T` that are assignable to `U` you can use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to achieve this, but in your example neither `T` nor `U` are union types and so `Exclude` is not directly useful.

So the first-order answer to your question is **no, there is no such `X` type that works this way**.

---

However, in TypeScript it is often the case that when no specific type will do, a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type can be used like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on a candidate type `V`.  So there's no `X`, but there might be an `X<V>` type such that `V` is assignable to `T` but not `U` if and only if `V extends X<V>`.

Here's the general way to write that:

```
type X<V extends T> = Exclude<V, U>;
```

In this case, `V` *must* extend `T`, or else you couldn't even write `X<V>`, so `T` is taken care of.  And so if `V extends X<V>`, then `V extends Exclude<V, U>`, which means that `V` cannot be a type assignable to `U` or a union of any types where any member is assignable to `U`.  This is as close to `T & not U` as we can get for arbitrary `T` and `U`.

Once you have a generic type like this, you'll want a generic helper function so that the compiler can infer the type argument and you don't have to write it out.  Something like:

```
const asX = <V extends T>(v: X<V>) => v;
```

So instead of `const val: X = {⋯}`, you'd write `const val = asX({⋯})`, which looks quite similar if you squint at it the right way.

---

Let's test it for your

```
interface T {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

interface U {
  foo: "baz";
}
```

types:

```
const xObj1 = asX({
  foo: "test",
  bar: 4
} as const); // okay

const xObj2 = asX({
  foo: "baz",
  bar: 2
} as const); // error
```

Looks good.  `xObj1` is accepted and `xObj2` is rejected.

Note that I used [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in each case; that's because your `U` happens to have a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for the `foo` property, but the compiler tends not to infer literal types for object properties.  If we left off `as const`, then `{foo: "baz", bar: 2}` would be inferred as `{foo: string, bar: number}`, and this is *not* assignable to `U`, so the compiler wouldn't have noticed the problem.  This is kind of a general issue to be aware of; type inference will strongly affect how these things work, so if you have particular non-arbitrary `T` and `U` types, you might need to tweak the `asX()` call signature so that you tend to get the inference you care about.  But without knowing more about `T` and `U` in advance, there's no specific advice to give other than "be careful".

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCrIN4ChnJge3wC5kBnMKUAcwG4dkAjOKEkAVwFsHo6BfLLKEixEKAKqZ6BYsgBETAF6y+AsAE8ADigAaAHgBqyCAA9IIACak0APmQBeZAFFjCADZtzEAwBpkY63RYCPgg5MhwpNr2yAZGphAWVqjWABQAbiR6+tYAlPa2aYHBoWDIxgDyDABWAIzREdop2LjSJLKQ5LLe9EwsyAAsWLzhVsXkOTTIAPRTyPgA1nBqAmOlFdUATPWRTVKEbYpdPcwkG0MjyKsT07PQUPhQWEA)